# How replace special character string in data frame ? R

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, mutate

I have the following data frame called `result`.

| MANUAL.ID | AUTO.ID | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | PYPPYP | L2 |
| PIPpip | NA | L1 |
| Barbar | NA | L5 |
| NA | Pippip | L3 |
| NA | Pippip,BerBar | L3 |

I try to replace all the different forms of a same tag by the right one. For example replace all PIPPIP and PIPpip by Pippip or Berbar by Barbar. To do this, I use a `mutate` function with `left_join` based on a required file called `tesaurus` which have column with all the possible case of a same tag (tag_id) and a column with the correct one (tag_ok) which looks like this :

| tag_id | tag_ok |
| --- | --- |
| PYPPYP | Pippip |
| PIPpip | Pippip |
| Pippip | Pippip |
| Barbar | Barbar |
| BerBar | Barbar |

I use the following code.

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape")
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
library("tidyr")
library("openxlsx")

tesaurus <- read.xlsx("Requested_files/sp_tesaurus.xlsx", sheet = "tesaurus") %>%
  select(-bat_sp)

result <- result %>%
  left_join(tesaurus, by = c(MANUAL.ID = "tag_id")) %>%
  mutate(MANUAL.ID = coalesce(tag_ok, MANUAL.ID)) %>%
  select(-tag_ok) %>%
  left_join(tesaurus, by = c(AUTO.ID = "tag_id")) %>%
  mutate(AUTO.ID = coalesce(tag_ok, AUTO.ID)) %>%
  select(-tag_ok)
```

This code works well for the MANUAL.ID column but for the AUTO.ID column because of the special case : Pippip,BerBar (there is two tags in one case)

How can I fix that ?

Comment: This does not quite handle all your cases, but I believe it is worth mentioning the `str_to_title()` from the `stringr` package, which would correctly change all words to title case (uppercase only in first character). If we did not have additional replacements like  `PYPPYP > Pippip` , we could even obviate the need for a lookup table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do it this way:
**Note** I think in **tesaurus** `Barbar` in tag_id should be `Berbar`:

```
tesaurus <- structure(list(tag_id = c("PYPPYP", "PIPpip", "Pippip", "Barbar", 
"BerBar"), tag_ok = c("Pippip", "Pippip", "Pippip", "Barbar", 
"Barbar")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**data:**

```
df <- structure(list(MANUAL.ID = c(NA, "PIPpip", "Barbar", NA, NA), 
    AUTO.ID = c("PYPPYP", NA, NA, "Pippip", "Pippip,BerBar"), 
    loc = c("L2", "L1", "L5", "L3", "L3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**Solution:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(loc, id, row), ~ifelse(str_detect(., paste(tesaurus$tag_id, collapse = "|")),
                              tesaurus$tag_ok, .)
  )) %>% 
  arrange(id, -row) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~toString(., na.rm=TRUE)), .by = c(id, loc)) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(id, loc), ~ifelse(str_detect(., "NA"), NA_character_, .))) %>% 
  select(contains("ID"), loc, -id)
```

```
  MANUAL.ID AUTO.ID        loc  
  <chr>     <chr>          <chr>
1 NA        Pippip         L2   
2 Pippip    NA             L1   
3 Pippip    NA             L5   
4 NA        Barbar         L3   
5 NA        Pippip, Barbar L3
```

Comment: but in this way the result in the 5th row (AUTO.ID column) is just Pippip and the expected one should be Pippip,Barbar

Comment: No for the 5th row column AUTO.ID the expexted result shoud be Pippip,Barbar and not Pippip, BerBar

Comment: Ok I jsut updated `tesaurus`. The code works now!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_replace_all` with a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("ID"), ~ str_replace_all(.x, deframe(tesaurus))))
```

-output

```
   MANUAL.ID       AUTO.ID loc
1      <NA>        Pippip  L2
2    Pippip          <NA>  L1
3    Barbar          <NA>  L5
4      <NA>        Pippip  L3
5      <NA> Pippip,Barbar  L3
```

Comment: this solution replace all the aAUTO.ID and MANUAL.ID columns by NA